# defaultValue on Select Element after load the options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any way to select the default value after loading the options?.

```
this.state = { option: localStorage.getItem('option') }
// option = 'sm' | 'qt' | 'gy' | ...

render(){
const storeNames = {sm: 'San Miguel', qt: 'Quito', gy: 'Guayaquil' } // This comes from a remote database
return (
<select defaultValue={this.state.option} onChange={e => {
    localStorage.setItem('option', e.target.value)
    this.setState({ option: e.target.value}) }}>
  { Object.keys(storeNames).map(storeNameIndex => (
    <option value={storeNameIndex} >{storeNames[storeNameIndex]}</option>      
  ))}
</select>
)}
```

The problem with this code is that it always selects the first option

Comment: A standard html <select> doesn't have a `defaltValue` attribute. Are you using a library for that element? If not try just setting `selected` on the appropriate option

Comment: I am using ReactJs, defaultValue is same that selected, it's a rule of the library

Comment: Don't see that in React forms docs themselves unless you have some other react extension library. React  docs suggest using option selected

Comment: Get this when I use selected `Warning: Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>.
    in option (at SearchTable.tsx:177)
    in select (at SearchTable.tsx:169)
    in div (at SearchTable.tsx:168)
    in SearchTable (at stockView.tsx:112)
    in div (at stockView.tsx:111)
    in StockView (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.tsx:133)
    in div (at App.tsx:125)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:66)
    in Router (at src/index.tsx:65)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:64)`

Comment: Ok...then all I can suggest is a more detailed comparison of the values in your dev tools console or React dev tools if you use that

Comment: Are you recommending that I ignore the recommendations and warnings that the library gives me?

Comment: No...suggesting more detailed value comparison of what is actually passed to the defaultValue compared to the option values. A codesandbox demo that reproduces issue would help

Comment: your code seems to work fine on codesandbox.io. Check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-wozniak-04v55?file=/src/App.js